# How should I handle RQ workers for overlapping batch processes

Tags: python, django, redis, python-rq

I've started using RQ / Redis to build out some asynchronous execution of some long running jobs for my django site. I'm hoping to do something like the following:

- I want one queue for each instance of a model. You can think of this model like an api user account.(there will not be a lot of these. 15 - 20 at most)
- I will be distributing batches of tasks (anywhere from 10 - 500) evenly across the queues. Multiple batches may be added before the first batch completes.
- With each batch, I would like to start up a worker for each queue that is not actively being worked on, and I would like to run these workers in batch mode, so that once they run out of tasks they will shut down.
- I realize I could just not run them in batch mode, and then I would always be working on / listening for work on all of the queues. The problem with this is that I would like to be able to add and remove queues dynamically, so it's better if it starts up the available queues with each batch.

I realize it might seem odd that I'm distributing tasks across the queues, but the reason for this is that each task in the same queue must be rate limited / throttled according to a service I'm using (think of it as an API rate limit, but where each queue represents a different account). But for my purposes it makes no difference which account the task is running on, so I might as well parallelize across all the accounts.

The problem that I am facing is that if I start a worker and give it a queue that is already being worked on, I now have two workers operating independently on that queue and so my expected throttling rate gets cut in half. How can I only start a worker if there is not already a worker operating on that queue? I could probably find a hacky solution to this, but I would prefer to handle it the "right" way and since I don't have much experience with queues I thought I should ask.

I am already implementing my own worker class so that I can dynamically control the queues, so I just need a way to add logic where if that queue is already being worked on, it will not be given a new worker. A simple version of my worker is here:

```
# custom_worker.py
import sys
from Api.models import *
from rq import Queue, Connection, Worker

# importing the necessary namespace for the tasks to run
from tasks import *

# dynamically getting the queue names in which I am expecting tasks
queues = [user.name for user in ApiUser.objects.all()]

with Connection():

    qs = list(map(Queue, queues)) or [Queue()]

    w = Worker(qs)

    w.work(burst=True)
```

Comment: For future readers: These days I would have many workers (who enforce their own rate limits), use a single queue, and utilize back pressure. Way easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a solution just meant diving into python-rq's source code a little bit. I might look into improving the documentation. Anyway, this seems to work for my needs!

```
import sys
from Api.models import *
from rq import Queue, Connection, Worker

# importing the necessary namespace for the tasks to run
from tasks import *

# Provide queue names to listen to as arguments to this script,
with Connection():

    current_workers = Worker.all()
    working_queues = [queue.name for worker in current_workers for queue in worker.queues]
    proposed_queues = [user.name for user in ApiUser.objects.all()]
    queues_to_start = [queue for queue in proposed_queues if not queue in working_queues]

    if len(queues_to_start) > 0:
        qs = list(map(Queue, queues_to_start))
        w = Worker(qs)
        w.work(burst=True)
    else:
        print("Nothing to do here.")
```

Comment: I am in a similar situation but I would like to be able to add new Queues during the runtime, Can this be done ? I haven't find much answers about this, I am using Flask btw.